# Usage of In app purchase in my app, requires information?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an app that can be  downloaded  from google play using `In-app purchase`.

1. I am using sample product id `android.test.purchased` to purchase product from google play. I am  able to purchase the product and getting toast message `Thank you. Your item will appear shortly` but i am unable to see logcat messages and item what i purchased . this is the code i am using

   ```
   public Handler mTransactionHandler = new Handler() {
   public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
       Log.i(TAG, "Transaction complete");
       Log.i(TAG, "Transaction status: " + BillingHelper.latestPurchase.purchaseState);
       Log.i(TAG, "Item purchased is: " + BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);

       if (BillingHelper.latestPurchase.isPurchased()) {
           Log.i(TAG, " is purchased completed ");
           showItem();
       }
   };
   ```

   };
2. If i use my own product Id for purchase, is it necessary to give original credit card details ?
   To purchase products, i am using test account as primary account in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs says that, to purchase own product for testing it is necessary to give original credit card details although funding (transaction of money) wont happens overthere..It seems to be virtual transaction from testing account..

Comment: that is ok, why i am unable to see the purchased product.

Comment: For that code i can able to see purchased product in my logcat dont know for you !!  :(

Comment: i just used dungeons example and nothing other than that buddy

Comment: guide me, even i am using that example i am unable to see the purchased item. even after i got success toast message after purchase item.